# Refer active choice parameter return values in active choice reactive parameter

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to refer active choice parameter return values in active choice reactive parameter.

I did the the following enter image description here

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
How do make refvariable to return 'abc' + some text append to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `return ["${name}"]` to `return [name]`

Comment: This didn't work for me, it is falling to the Fallback Script this way. I couldn't find any solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

Force the result from a GString to a String, by changing

```
return ["${name}"]
```

to

```
return ["${name}".toString()]
```